# Why .Where() doesn't work with .Include()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I need to fetch chats that have current user as a participant, and want to fetch only active users.

I execute the following query:

```
var query = _db.Chats
            .Include(c => c.Participants.Where(cu=>cu.IsActive))
            .Include(c=>c.LastMessage)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Sender)
            .ThenInclude(cu => cu.User)
            .Where(c =>
                c.Participants.Any(cu => cu.UserId == _currentUser.MessengerUserId))
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.LastMessage != null ? c.LastMessage.Timestamp : c.Created)
            .AsNoTracking();
```

but participants filtering part doesn't work - all the users are included, while it works as intended with 'select only chats with current user as participant' condition.

[Code with Resharper annotations image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDA6h.png)

[PostgreSQL script generated](https://pastebin.com/Bvsxju91)

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider?

Comment: can you send show classes? can you tell  version EF ?can you see tsql Generated (when you execute query can get data)?

Comment: @NetMage I use EF Core 7 (I believe) with NpgSql.

Comment: I don’t exactly need it this way. Just need to select only active participants for the chats

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi https://github.com/Rostand-Corp/flitch-backend/tree/develop/src/Domain/Entities for entities. The code I’ve written above is currently not in the repo

Comment: You say "participants filtering part doesn't work" than you say "all the users are included" - which part isn't working in the code? Are you trying to filter participants or users?

Comment: @NetMage I want to filter participants. I want my resulting List<Chat> to have only active participants. But at this moment it includes every participant regardless the status.
I have moved AsNoTracking() to the very top and removed Where() clause I had at the bottom just to test and it still doesn't work (still includes every user)

Comment: I’ve discovered that having Select() in a query shadows Include filters. Down the query I have Mapster doing its ProjectTo which I believe is Select(). Tomorrow I will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved. After reading some documentation I figured out that Select() shadows Include(). Down the query I had Mapster’s ProjectToType<>() extension method which I believe has executed some Selects (which also explains why some of the non-included properties were included). After removing ProjectToType<>() everything started working just fine as Selects gone.